# Unable to design/print 2D array

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to pass and print a dynamic 2D array object using iReport Designer.

My simple datasource is as below (this is dynamic with n rows and columns in real time):

```
Object [][] myData = new Object [][] {{"RECORD1"}, {"RECORD2"}};
```

I pass this to the `JasperDataSourceBuilder` class:

I have written the following code for the same:

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRField;

public class JasperDataSourceBuilder implements JRDataSource {

    private static int rowIndex = 0;
    private static int columnIndex = -1;

    private Object[][] data = null;

    public JasperDataSourceBuilder(Object[][] dataObject){
        data = dataObject;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean next() throws JRException {
        boolean hasMore = false;
        if((data != null && data.length > 0)){
            if(rowIndex < data.length){
                columnIndex++;
                if(columnIndex < data[rowIndex].length){
                    hasMore = true;
                }else{
                    rowIndex ++;
                    columnIndex = 0;
                    hasMore = true;
                }
            }
          }
        return hasMore;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getFieldValue(JRField arg0) throws JRException {
        return String.valueOf(data[rowIndex][columnIndex]);
    }

    public Object[][] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object[][] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

When I call my `report()` method the PDF is generated but only the first row is printed in the report.

My jrxml is as below

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="4f311e4c-b629-4c6c-a718-451aec9c679e">
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#A9A9A9">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFBFBF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BBA8A8">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFE6E6">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#FFF8F8"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="dataset1" uuid="15c5b3b7-2873-4678-a6ad-67db2344acaa"/>
    <field name="field1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[RECORD HEADER]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="94" y="2" width="100" height="20" uuid="cdfaad19-02d4-4846-9b06-c71a7df3c92f"/>
                <text><![CDATA[RECORD HEADER]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="94" y="55" width="100" height="20" uuid="d154b00a-f10d-4803-9901-4580080fc982"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I want to use JasperReports in my application where currently I use itextPDF where in my data is all two dimensional object which displays tables with Headers & Data.

I want to keep this `Object[][]` as a datasource and implement it in my existing reports.

Comment: I found a reference at - http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/#customdatasource

Answer (score 0):

I could use Object[][] as a datasource successfully.

In the below class I iterate over my 2D object & return the value.
The getFieldValue method simply returns the correct value form the next index of a 2D Object. (Make sure to match the no of column fields in JRXML with your 2D Object)

```
public class JasperDataSourceBuilder implements JRDataSource {

    private int rowIndex = 0;
    private int columnIndex = 0;

    private Object[][] data = null;

    public JasperDataSourceBuilder(Object[][] dataObject){
        data = dataObject;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean next() throws JRException {
        boolean hasMore = false;
        if((data != null && data.length > 0)){
            if(rowIndex < data.length){
                if(columnIndex < data[rowIndex].length){
                    hasMore = true;
                }else{
                    rowIndex ++;
                    columnIndex = 0;
                    hasMore = true;
                }
            }
          }
        if(rowIndex >= data.length){
            hasMore = false;
        }
        return hasMore;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getFieldValue(JRField arg0) throws JRException {
        String fieldVal = String.valueOf(data[rowIndex][columnIndex]);
        columnIndex++;
        return fieldVal;
    }

    public Object[][] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object[][] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Then generate the report by using the code below -

```
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
        reportStream, parameters, new  JasperDataSourceBuilder(dataObject)); 
String fileName = "report2.PDF";
response.setContentType("application/pdf;charset=ISO-8859-1");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
OutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, ouputStream);
ouputStream.flush();
ouputStream.close();
```

The above can be achieved by extending **AbstractTableModel** too, but for my requirement & simplicity I will be implementing **JRDataSource** as above.

I found the reference link in above comment very useful.

Hope this helps some one new to JasperReports.

Thanks !!